# How to create a dialog from a class which extends DialogFragment?

Tags: android, dialog

So I looked at the code on developer.android.com
According to them this is the way things to be done ...

```
public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User cancelled the dialog
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
    return builder.create();
}
}
```

and I want the object of this class to be created when an item is clicked from the option menu ...
But I don't know how to do that ???

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you want a way to tell another class when the user clicks "Ok".  A common approach is to create your own listener, the Developer's Guide has a [great example](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#EventCallbacks) of this.

---

**The Basics**
Create a callback:

```
public static class FragmentA extends ListFragment {
    ...
    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnMyEventListener {
        public void onMyEvent();
    }
    ...
}
```

Set the callback:

```
public static class FragmentA extends ListFragment {
    OnMyEventListener mListener;
    ...
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mListener = (OnMyEventListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnMyEventListener");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Call the callback:

```
.setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
         // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
         mListener.onMyEvent();
     }
})
```

Comment: It is the same process, on the most basic level just replace ListFragment with DialogFragment. What class do you want to send "Fire zee missles" to?

Comment: `FIRE ZE MISSILES!` end of ze world reference detected, now googling albinoblacksheep.com

Answer (score 1):

MainActiviy:

```
//Displaying the dialog box
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FireMissilesDialogFragment fmdl = new FireMissilesDialogFragment(MainActivity.this);
fmdl.show(fragmentManager,"dialog");
```

Add this to your FireMissilesDialogFragment.java:

```
Context context;
public FireMissilesDialogFragment(Context context) {
   this.context = context;
}
....
....
rest of the code
```